# How To Configure Fields To Display In Ubercart Product Node

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I have set up ubercart on a site and everything seems ok when adding products and viewing the catalog page however when I click on the product the product view does not include the product image or the price.

I have have enabled all fields in admin/store/settings/products/edit/fields however this does not seem to change anything (SKU etc not displayed either, only description, size options, add to cart button and link to category)

Can anyone suggest why these may not be showing, Am I looking at completely the wrong config screen? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here admin/content/node-type/product/display if the display for the Full node is OK.
Another way will be to create a node-product.tpl.php template and display the fields as you wish (You'll have $node there, etc..).

Comment: I ended up editing node-product.tpl.php which seemed to work thanks. One thing is that my left sidebar block (with my shopping cart and category) is not displayed. How can I include this in my node?

Comment: Fixed it - was just a missing end div.